# How to select multiple characters at once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, select

I use this javascript code to select character "," in html div.

```
var word = ',';
var replacement = '<span class="myword">' + word + '</span>';

var re = new RegExp(word, 'ig');

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacement);
```

This code only work for select one character, but i need new code to select multi character at once in html.
 Characters i want to select is : "," & "/" & "،".
**Please help me to solve this.Thanks** 
My full page code:

```js
var word = ',';
var replacement = '<span class="myword">' + word + '</span>';

var re = new RegExp(word, 'ig');

document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacement);
```

```css
.myword
{
    color:red;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
 <div class="my-page">
    <div class="cats">
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">steel</a>
        ,
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">plastic</a>
        ،
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">silver</a>
        /
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">fake</a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array for this purpose and then loop through that array.

Good Luck.

```js
var to_replace = [",", " / ", "،"];
for (i = 0; i < to_replace.length; i++)
{
    var word = to_replace[i];
    var replacement = '<span class="myword">' + word + '</span>';
    var re = new RegExp(word, 'ig');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacement);
}
```

```css
.myword
{
    color:red;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
<div class="my-page">
    <div class="cats">
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">steel</a> , <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">plastic</a> ، <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">silver</a> / <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">fake</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just created an array of the desired markers and wrapped your script with a loop through the array. I hope this is helpful.

```js
const words = [",", "،"];
function iterateNReplace(word){
var replacement = '<span class="myword">' + word + '</span>';
var re = new RegExp(word,'ig');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(re, replacement);
            
};

words.forEach(word => iterateNReplace(word));
```

```css
.myword
{
    color:orange;
    font-size: 25px
}
```

```html
 <div class="my-page">
    <div class="cats">
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">steel</a>
        ,
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">plastic</a>
        ،
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">silver</a>
        /
        <a href="https://example.com" rel="tag">fake</a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for help but your code is incomplete because does not select "/"